# DApps with fiat currency?

Tags: dapps, dapp-design, hyperledger

Is it possible to build DApp which can accept Fiat currency? Because for an existing business to move to blockchain, the existing users should be able to transition to DApp seamlessly. I would like to propose a blockchain solution without hurting the current user base.

Does any blockchain offer this solution? Is hyperledger an option?

Thanks in advance for your time and response.

Comment: It is impossible to support fiat currency in a fully decentralized way, because fiat currency is not decentralized. Using the strict definition of DApp it cannot be done. You should think about what you are trying to accomplish and how it will benefit everyone. If you're using the blockchain because it helps solve a problem, that's great. If you're using the blockchain just because it sounds cool, there is no truly useful advice for you because your project serves no useful purpose.

Comment: It definitely solves many problems that exists in the current application but asking 1000s of users to create an ethereum account and then let them use the DApp is going to make us lose the existing customers. I'm thinking from customer's perceptive on how to keep it seamless for them.

Comment: You need a digital representation of the fiat currency (i.e. token) to ensure that your Dapp can autonomously service asset transfers. There are many tokens that are pegged to fiat currencies (stablecoins). The vast majority are pegged to the USD.

Answer (score 2):

In Ethereum, the closest you can get to a fiat currency is to use `DAI`, a decentralised stable coin. It was created by [MakerDao](https://makerdao.com/) and, despite being at the beginning, they are doing a great job. `DAI` is 10x better than other centralised solutions which merely peg the token to a `USD` bank account.

To address your question, there is no way around the problem other than:

1. Integrating with a third-party exchange and ask customers to sign-up there (KYC will most likely apply)
2. Depending on the nature of your business (whether you allows users to keep money on your website), you may be able to exchange their money to `ETH`, on demand, by connecting to a [decentralised exchange](https://github.com/distribuyed/index). To preclude volatility risks, you could keep the business' funds in `DAI`.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop the DApp to do whatever you want, for example, you can make a cryptocurrency exchange DApp and accept any payment in fiat money you want. But this DApp would have to use another technology to convert fiat into `Ether` because Ethereum doesn't provide any exchange services. It provides APIs only to work inside the blockchain, not outside it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually yes but requires that you clarify the meaning of DApp. In most cases a DApp solution will involve both an onchain component (smart contract) and an offchain component (e.g. web or mobile application). While the onchain code can only transact in ETH, the offchain component of your DApp is free to transact in any currency your solution requires. You can then determine which parts of the transaction and currency conversions you wish to expose to the end user.

If accepting fiat is important for your solution, then feel free to do so. There is no requirement that your users even know that underneath you are calling into a smart contract and transacting in ETH.